# How to send notifications to users based on api response time in ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I using push notification in my application with Firebase.

I send the notifications from Firebase cloud messaging it will working fine notifications are go to users in all states like Baground, Active and suspended.

But in my scenario is when user confirm the order with api response on that time I want to send the notification.

How to we make it please give any idea or sample reference.

Comment: This will be done from your backhand ask backhand developer to to integrate firebase push from his side , You have to pass device token when app launch

Comment: just to be sure, you need to show a notification when the user receives a response for confirmation?

Comment: In addition to @PrashantTukadiya comment. You can use Firebase Cloud functions for that matter. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Answer (score 0):

Once when you receive success on the device, after the API call you can schedule local notification which can be displayed in the same way as a push notification.

You can check this [site](https://medium.com/quick-code/local-notifications-with-swift-4-b32e7ad93c2)

And this is an example code:

```
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "Test title"
   content.body =  "Test body"
   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
   let uuidString =  UUID().uuidString
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
   let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```